Recommended tool for reducing image filesize while sacrificing image quality as little as possible
SquareSpace limits image uploads to a maximum of 20MB.
I normally upload PNG images that are resized using Pixillion to 2000px on their longest side.
Most of the time the results are good but sometimes the resized images have issues related to pixelation or colour compared to the originals. When this happens I usually replace the resized images with those supplied. However some image sets contain images greater than 20Mb and I need to find the best way to reduce the file size to less than 20Mb (I'll settle for 19.99Mb) with the minimum loss of overall quality.
I'm looking for a tool that can resize large images to a maximum of 20MB with the minimum loss of quality.
I'm more concerned with the quality of the image than whether the image is 19.9MB vs. 2MB.

Purchasing a Photoshop subscription is not an option.

I currently use GIMP for most of my image manipulation.

I've tried online resizers but found they do excessive compression, or after uploading an image, did nothing (eg. Adobe Free Image Resizer).

I don't mind paying a small amount for a piece of software that solves the problem, but funds are limited.


I know that SquareSpace processes the images after they're uploaded, but I want to start with images that provide the best outcome.
Further investigation of the images as they finally get processed by SquareSpace shows they are considerably further compressed. For example see this page , the original header image is 20.949Mb. I reduced it to 16.748Mb to get it to upload, but the image at the top of the page appears to be only 774Kb. DPI gets changed from 300 to 72, but I suppose that's inevitable.
Sometimes the images as displayed are very similar to the originals, but sometimes they are pixilated and / or there are colour shifts (usually the images are "dull"). Can anyone suggest suitable software or a web-based tool, or GIMP settings that meet my needs?
========
Background information
I build the pages for a web based lifestyle magazine Nataal. The editor sends me a Word doc copy file, a pack of images and some guidance as to how the resultant page is to be laid out.
The articles come from multiple sources as do the images.
I normally pre-process all the images to convert them into standard sized png files. Then I build the page.
I cannot insert one of the original image files here as there is a limit of 10Mb and I am discussing 20Mb+ images.

There are multiple factors at play here. Your question would benefit from linking a sample image before compression and after and also indicating if the issues with image quality are seen before upload or after SquareSpace recompresses them. The nature of an image affects what formats are best and what tools are best. What solves one problem may not solve another. If there is a way to prepare your images so that they are not resized and/or recompressed by SqSp that would be ideal. 20MB images seem large from a 1000 feet up.

@Blindspots I agree. About 95% of all image sets get accepted without complaint. So I must be doing something right! I rarely see any problems with the resized images before I upload them. Maybe part of the problem is incompatible colour spaces? I am adding a section called "Background Information" to the question as it would be too long for a comment.

It would be great to have some source files to look at.  Maybe isolate what its going on.

What formats does that support? You should list them as lack of that clearly lead to an inaccurate answer. Using something that doesn't support WEBP with requirement of such big images is generally not a good idea these days. Is this correct? https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/206542517-Formatting-your-images-for-display-on-the-web

@Destroy666. You are quite right, thanks. I've added that link into my question. Maybe I didn't make it clear, the vast majority of the images do not attract any adverse comments by the original providers, just a few and mostly the very big images  that will inevitably suffer when resized to web. Particularly as SquareSpace does its own compression completely beyond our control. We are stuck with SquareSpace for now as migrating well over 1000 pages to a new content management system would be prohibitively expensive if even possible.

There are many many options and no universal solution. I will try recommending the most suitable ones for your workflow, but keep in mind JPG and PNG formats have their limitations and you may not find the perfect solution for certain images, depending on how complex in terms of pixel differences they are.
If you'd like to check quality and random algorithms and different options on the fly, you likely won't find anything better than Squoosh:

you can see the original/modified images and drag the slider to compare them, after each change you make
it displays the size and its loss/gain
you can also reduce the resolution if needed



Another option to use within your system is RIOT. It has quite similar functionality, but works fully offline and can also attempt to resize below a given threshold optimally.

Thanks, I've never seen that app before, but it looks as if I can try it on the most "awkward" images to try and get the best uploaded image.
